# How can i assign task to users automatically so that all users can have the same number of task

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am building an auto task manager that will automatically assign a task to users with the same role as the role of the task. Right now I am getting the total number of users with the same role as the task and then use `math.random()`  to generate a number from 0 to the length of the users that have the same role and the assign the task to that random user. This isn't efficient as a user can have 10 tasks and another user has just 4 tasks. Is there a way I can assign tasks sequentially to all the users with the same role with the task??
This is the code to that creates a new task:

```
exports.createNewTask = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let task = new Task({
      title: req.body.title,
      description: req.body.description,
      role: req.body.role,
      priority:req.body.priority
    });
    let role = req.body.role;
    let user = await User.find({ role: role });
    if(user.length == 0) {
       res.status(500).json({message:"Please Create a User With this role" });
    }

    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * user.length);
    let assignedUser = user[random]._id;
    task.user = assignedUser;
    let assignedTask = await task.save()
    res.status(200).json({ assignedTask });


  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({ error: err });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. i'd add a new field to `User` such as `NumTasksAssigned` which would keep a count of how many tasks a user has. if you don't like to manage this count manually, you could also get this count by doing a `$lookup` when retrieving the users for a given role.
2. when getting the list of users for a given role, retrieve them sorted in ascending order by the `NumTasksAssigned` field. also limit the number of users returned by how many tasks you have at hand.
3. iterate over the user list and assign tasks to users and increase their task count.

if the number of tasks at hand is greater than the amount of users retrieved, don't break the loop and keep assigning until there are no more tasks to assign.

the main problem with this approach is that users who already had some tasks would get more tasks assigned to them.

we could come up with some algorithm to prevent this from happening and assign tasks evenly. but it may not be a complication you'd wanna deal with.

**update:** added lookup query

```
var numTasks = 10;
var roleName = "some role";

db.users.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { role: roleName }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "tasks",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "user",
            as: "tasks"
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            tasks: { $size: "$tasks" }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { tasks: 1 }
    },
    {
        $limit: numTasks
    }
])
```

Comment: Please can you explain number 2 better?``` let user = await User.aggregate([
      {$lookup:{
      from: 'tasks',
        localField: '_id',
        foreignField: 'user',
        as: 'tasks'
      }},{ $sort : { tasks : 1 } }
    ])``

Comment: i wrote the lookup code and have sorted it in ascending order

Comment: @wisdom say you have 10 tasks that needs to be assigned. and there's 20 users in the db for the given role. there's no need to retrieve all 20 users. just put a limit on the retrieved number of users. i've updated my answer with a full lookup query.

Comment: @wisdom on second thoughts, i think i've misready your question. you only have 1 task that needs to be assigned at a time yes? if so, simply limit by 1. that is set `numTasks=1`. that way only a single user who has the minimum number of tasks will be returned by mongo.

Comment: Ok..i get it now...but i think there is an issue with the $set aggregate....it returns this:`"errmsg": "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$set'",`

Comment: @wisdom your mongodb must be older than 4.2. i've updated my answer with `$addFields` which should work with older versions.

Comment: Thanks so much...i'm really grateful...it is working fine